# How to serialize struct which implements IEnumerable using protobuf-net and surrogate

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm using the `protobuf-net` package version 3.0.101.

The following code generates a runtime exception when executing `typeModel.Serialize(ms, value)`. The exception is:

```
GenericArguments[0], 'UserQuery+Option`1[System.Int32]', on 'ProtoBuf.Serializers.RepeatedSerializer`2[TCollection,T] CreateEnumerable[TCollection,T]()' violates the constraint of type 'TCollection'.
```

```cs
void Main()
{
    var typeModel = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
    typeModel.SetSurrogate<Option<int>, OptionSurrogate<int>>();
    //typeModel[typeof(Option<int>)].IgnoreListHandling = true; // This doesn't help.
    
    var value = new Option<int>(true, 5);
    
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    typeModel.Serialize(ms, value);
}

struct Option<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public Option(bool hasValue, T value)
    {
        HasValue = hasValue;
        Value = value;
    }

    public readonly bool HasValue;

    public readonly T Value;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (HasValue) {
            yield return Value;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

[ProtoContract]
struct OptionSurrogate<T>
{
    public OptionSurrogate(Option<T> thing) {
        HasValue = thing.HasValue;
        Value = thing.Value;
    }
    
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public readonly bool HasValue;
    
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public readonly T Value;

    public static implicit operator Option<T>(OptionSurrogate<T> surrogate) => new Option<T>(surrogate.HasValue, surrogate.Value);
    public static implicit operator OptionSurrogate<T>(Option<T> value) => new OptionSurrogate<T>(value);
}
```

There are two things that will fix this:

1. Changing `struct Option<T>` to `class Option<T>`
2. Removing `IEnumerable<T>` from `struct Option<T>`

However, neither of these are possible because the `struct` I want to serialize is in a 3rd party library.

Is this a bug in `protobuf-net` or is there a workaround?

Comment: This looks like it may be related, but I tried cherry-picking it and it didn't help: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/pull/755

Answer (score 1):

<s>One possible workaround that might work is *wrapping* the object in your own class, where you will be able to control which properties get serialized and how.</s>

So I pulled the `protobuf` repo and stepped through their code for surrogate handling for `IEnumerable<T>`(the `Option<T>`) and their implementation makes **heavy** assumptions that any `IEnumerable<T>` is an `ICollection` by default leading to this error. **Despite** the fact that you explicitly give the runtime the information that `Option<T>` is not serializable using `SetSurrogate`, their implementation does not check surrogates until after the item it **packed** into a more manageable `Enumerable` type. The problem here is that they're trying to pack:

```cs
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    if (HasValue) {
        yield return Value;
    }
}
```

and that's not possible (in-fact they don't even 'see'/'look' for this kind of implementation of IEnumerable.

All that being said, I recommend just explictly casting the objects before and after deserialization, I provided an example that I got working below.

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var typeModel = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

    var value = new Option<int>(true, 5);

    using var writer = new FileInfo("test.txt").OpenWrite();

    typeModel.Serialize(writer , (OptionSurrogate<int>)value, typeModel);

    writer .Dispose();

    using var reader = new FileInfo("test.txt").OpenRead();

    Option<int> deserializedValue = (OptionSurrogate<int>)typeModel.Deserialize(reader, null, typeof(OptionSurrogate<int>));

}
```

**Edit**
Added simple implementation of `ICollection<T>` to possibly prevent constraint error

**Edit**
Added Working work-around this time.

**Editors Note**
I am not an expert at `protobuf` and my opinion of how and why this bug is happening is based on some *very* simple debugging and stepping through their github source. This should not be taken as a fact as I neither wrote `protobuf` or have worked with the source code of `protobuf` long enough to properly opine on the cause of this error.

Comment: Thanks that would work for some use cases, but in my use case I need to directly serialize `Option<T>`

Comment: Have you tried implementing `ICollection` into the wrapper? That [may solve the `TCollection` constraint violation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64394747/custom-linq-extension-method-throws-verificationexception-type-argument-ienumer)

Comment: Good idea, I tried it and it still didn't work unfortunately

Comment: I went ahead and did some deeper digging for you checkout the updated post, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your efforts, unfortunately we are consuming this type as a generic parameter inside another wrapper, so don't really have control over casting values. I can add special handling but I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Sorry about that, unfortunately it looks like a limitation on the current implementation of protobuf requires a bit of special handling. =(