# Unable to cast object of type 'ColumnExpression' to type 'EntityProjectionExpression'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this computed property on my entity (`[Computed]` comes from [delegate decompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler))

```
[Computed]
public IReadOnlyCollection<ReferenceType> ReferenceTypes => _addressReferenceTypes
    .Select(referenceType => referenceType.ReferenceType)
    .ToArray();
```

which I would like to keep as `IReadOnlyCollection`, but when I perform queries against this table I get an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.ColumnExpression' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityProjectionExpression'.

It seems to work if I do this

```
[Computed]
public IEnumerable<ReferenceType> ReferenceTypes => _addressReferenceTypes
    .Select(referenceType => referenceType.ReferenceType);
```

But ideally I would like to keep it as `IReadOnlyCollection` (since it is readonly)

Does anyone know how I can achieve this, or what the error means?

---

I also saw the same error when trying to project to a collection on my dto in my `IQueryable<Dto>` before passing to the db

```
myQueryable.Select(x => 
    new Dto 
    {
        Items = x.someCondition ? x.Items : null
    });
```

Comment: Not sure that it will help but try using `ToList` instead of `ToArray` previously EF in some cases had different problems handling some [type of collections/LINQ projection methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64397542/2501279).

Comment: @GuruStron unfortunately it gives me the same error, when keeping the prop type as `IReadOnlyCollection` and replacing `ToArrray` with `ToList`

Comment: To start with, what EF Core version are you targeting, what  is `[Computed]` and where it comes from? There is no such attribute in EF Core. The one I know is from DelegateDecompiler 3rd party package,  but you have to confirm that (also including the version) and how you plug it into EF Core. And in general specify such things in the question when using non standard libraries. The error itself is not interesting and simply means "unexpected", as usual when the execution hits some point where the code expects something and gets something else.

Comment: Also if it works for `IEnumerable<T>`, then keep it that way - it is also read only. In fact `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>` and just adds `Count` property. In some different implementation/naming conventions it could have been named `IEnumerableWithCount<T>` or something like that  :)

Comment: I don't know if this information is useful, but `SqlExpressions.ColumnExpression` represents querying a single column and `EntityProjectionExpression` represents all the columns of a single type. Both are types used by EF Core during query compilation. So for some reason, part way through compiling your query, ef core has confused if your expression relates to a single value or an entire type. If you included more of the stack trace, we might be able to tell exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the reason for this is, but for my first issue I just kept it as `IEnumerable`

For the second issue, where the error was thrown on conditionally projecting some collection to my dto, I changed the select to

```
myQueryable.Select(x => 
    new Dto 
    {
        Items = x.Items.Where(y => x.someCondition)
    });
```